# Https listener .NET failed on port 443

Tags: https, httplistener

I am developing a http listener to access a remote process. Example code snippet:

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("https://*:443/");
listener.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Listening...");
for (; ; )
{
HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
new Thread(new Worker(ctx).ProcessRequest).Start();
}
```

This is working as expected if I use port 8080, but fails on port 443. The exception is

```
System.Net.HttpListenerException was unhandled
Message=The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Comment: Please indent your code in the future. That would make it easier for other people to read your code.

Comment: You also need to bind ssl cert to port, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure that is there any other web sites (in IIS or Apache) serving through the port 443 with SSL? It should be the common cause for the reported issue.

You may try some other port to see if the same exception is thrown by HttpListener object.

Comment: Hi Karthick, Thank you very much for the information. I use command netstat -o -n -a to see the used Port list and found skype is using that port. After removing is the issue is resolved.