# HttpListener with HTTPS on MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, https, xamarin.ios, httplistener

I implemented a very simple web server using the `HttpListener` in MonoTouch. Everything is working fine. Now I need to add HTTPS support. I tried to follow the steps from

[Httplistener with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support)

but I don't know where to set the certificates in MonoTouch. Just adding the prefix "https://*:443" doesn't help, as no connections are possible and no exceptions are thrown.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx, this might be because one has to specify a server certificate ("You can configure Server Certificates and other listener options by using HttpCfg.exe").

How can I do it in MonoTouch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a very good question. In some cases, like for `HttpListener`, .NET requires tools or .config files (using `System.Configuration`) to tweak the configuration of an application. In many cases there are API do achieve the same purpose, but not always (and not in this case).

The solution is to look at Mono's source code to see what it expects the `HttpCfg.exe` tool to setup for the application. From [github](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System/System.Net/EndPointListener.cs#L77):

```
string dirname = Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string path = Path.Combine (dirname, ".mono");
path = Path.Combine (path, "httplistener");
string cert_file = Path.Combine (path, String.Format ("{0}.cer", port));
if (!File.Exists (cert_file))
    return;
string pvk_file = Path.Combine (path, String.Format ("{0}.pvk", port));
if (!File.Exists (pvk_file))
    return;
cert = new X509Certificate2 (cert_file);
key = PrivateKey.CreateFromFile (pvk_file).RSA;
```

So the solution is to create the same directory structure (it's possible since it will point under the `Documents` directory) and copy the `.cer` file (binary DER-encoded certificate) and the `.pvk` file (which is the private key in the format that `makecert` creates) with the port number as the file name.

With those files in place you should be able to start the `HttpListener` and have it load the required certificate and private key required to handle SSL requests.

Comment: In order for it to work, the <port>.cer and <port>.pvk files must reside in <application's document directory>/.config/.mono/httplistener

Comment: Thanks for posting this!!  I assuming you got this working in MonoTouch?  I'm trying to get it working on Monodroid.  I can't figure out how to get the cert and pvk files in the right place.  I added them as "Assets" but that didn't seem to work. :-(

Comment: Is it just me or does this defeat the purpose of HTTPS, since it would not be that hard to simply download the private key out of the bundle, or off of the filesystem?

Comment: @exvance did you ever figure out where to store the files?