# servicestack selfhosted on Windows2008 r2 over https without IIS

Tags: https, servicestack

I have implemented servicestack v3.9.71 selfhost on windows2008r2. I have certificate files. how to activate https on servicestack and how to refer to certificate files. Thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 1):

Configuring SSL for ServiceStack Self Hosts is configured the same way for all HttpListener's, i.e. it's not specific to ServiceStack - and it needs to be configured on the OS where it's run.

This answer shows how to [configure SSL on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/85785) whilst this answer should help showing how you can [configure SSL on Linux/Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23245818/85785).

You should be able to use https with ServiceStack HttpListener self-host by [following the steps in the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/85785), using "https://*:8443/" for the url and "CN=localhost" should bypass the SSL browser warning dialog.

It's not specifically clear in the answer but you can get the Thumbprint from the **details tab** of the certificate where you then need to remove spaces. You can then [follow the walkthrough in the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905011/85785) to use MMC to import the certificate.