# 'PrivateKey' does not have a definition for 'CreateFromFile'

Tags: c#, mono, private-key, httplistener

I am trying to implement a solution into my application that mirrors the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379963/httplistener-with-https-on-monotouch/13385734#13385734)

I have a similar scenario where I have an `HttpListener` and `Grapevine` based application running on an Ubuntu server that I need to get working with `HTTPS` using `Mono` and I am trying to create and include the relevant keys to allow `HTTPS`

The problem I am having is the last line of the solution,

`key = PrivateKey.CreateFromFile (pvk_file).RSA;`

When I try the same Visual Studio shows an error/text highlighted red, `'PrivateKey' does not have a definition for 'CreateFromFile'`

Am I using the wrong libraries or is something else the issue with my code itself?

My code, cut down to the relevant method.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading;
using java.security;

public class ConfigureCertificates
    {
        private readonly string _dirName;
        private readonly string _path;
        private readonly string _port;
        private readonly string _certFile;
        public ConfigureCertificates(string port)
        {
            _dirName = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
            _path = Path.Combine(_dirName, ".mono");
            _path = Path.Combine(_path, "httplistener");
            _port = port;
            _certFile = Path.Combine(_path, String.Format("{0}.cer", _port));
        }

        public void SetUpCerts()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(_certFile))
               throw new Exception("Certificate file not found");

            string pvkFile = Path.Combine(_path, String.Format("{0}.pvk", _port));

            if (!File.Exists(pvkFile))
                throw new Exception("Private key not found");

            var cert = new X509Certificate2(_certFile);
            var key = PrivateKey.CreateFromFile(pvkFile).RSA; // Error occurs here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try the full namespace, perhaps there is a clash of class names here. `Mono.Security.Authenticode.PrivateKey.CreateFromFile()`

Comment: That was spot on. Thanks. Just had to add `Mono.Security` from Nuget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a naming clash - in other words there is another class called `PrivateKey` that doesn't have the method you require. [A quick Google hunt](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Authenticode/PrivateKey.cs) indicates the correct class is in the `Mono.Security.Authenticode` namespace. So you will need to reference the full path:

```
Mono.Security.Authenticode.PrivateKey.CreateFromFile(...)
```

You may also need to add the `Mono.Security` package if you don't already have it.