# Android HttpListener using SSL?

Tags: c#, android, ssl, xamarin.android, httplistener

I'm developing a android app that hosts a web server using the `HttpListener` class.

But i need to host it using a `SSL` certificate, I have read somewhere that you need to place the certificate in a special directory on the android device.

But i have lost the link that specified exactly where.

So does any one know how to get `HTTPS` to work on `Xamarin` Android with the `HttpListener` class?

Edit:
I have tired to store a `.cer` and `.pvk` file under `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), ".mono", "httplistener")` as suggested in [HttpListener with HTTPS on MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379963) but when i try to access the url i get no answer, if i change to http i at least get a answer.

I found the following source code on github, https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/3f779475e3fc982e312212d5dbbd86515eddfc0c/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListener.Mono.cs#L73

But it just eats any exception that occures so there is no way to figure out if anything goes wrong!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpListener with HTTPS on MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379963/httplistener-with-https-on-monotouch)

Comment: @NicolasDusart correct me if im wrong but `MonoTouch` is for iOS not android.

Comment: did you ever manage to get it to work?

Comment: I gave up and switched to a web socket server instead.

Comment: I have recently implemented HTTPListener and allow communication over LAN as well by add firewall rule. There is no any input required, everything is handled by C# code. I have shared full code of the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149405/983548

Answer (score 0):

You've not indicated what you're calling the file itself, looking at the mono code for System.Net.HttpListener the file itself must be {port number}.cer, i.e. 443.cer if you were to listen on 443.

```
string dirname = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string path = Path.Combine(dirname, ".mono");
path = Path.Combine(path, "httplistener");
string cert_file = Path.Combine(path, String.Format("{0}.cer", port));
```

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/3f779475e3fc982e312212d5dbbd86515eddfc0c/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpListener.Mono.cs#L64