# http listener with https support coded in c#

Tags: c#, https, certificate, httplistener

I found a lot of answers how to set httplistener up to use HTTPS, but each one solution requires the use of command line. I guess that is the fastest way to do it but I would like to  write C# class to handle this.

In old solution I used webserver class (found somewhere on Internet, I don't remember exact name) which allowed to add certificate in that way:

```
webserver.Certificate = new X509Certificate2("MyCert.pfx", "MyPassword");
```

Is there way to achieve this with httplistener? From code obviously.

Regards.

Comment: What command line command are you trying to duplicate in C#? Seems like you should start by making your http listener work, using the That way you'll know *exactly* what setup commands you need to duplicate in C# code.

Comment: My httplistener works perfectly but my employer insists on encrypted connection. This solution ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support ) contains all I need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load a certificate with:

```
X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2("MyCert.pfx");
```

And then install it:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
if (!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
{
    store.Add(cert);
}
store.Close();
```

Of course you might have to change the store name or location for your particular app.

For running the netsh command, you could look into creating and running a process (i.e. [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.Process.Start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) and run netsh.exe. Otherwise you have to mess with the Win32 [HttpSetServiceConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, or the .NET equivalent if there is one.

You might find this codebox article useful: http://dotnetcodebox.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-work-with-ssl-certificate.html

Comment: I have published the code from the blog as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SslCertBinding.Net/). Feel free to use it. Example of full certificate installation can be found in [unit tests](https://github.com/segor/SslCertBinding.Net/blob/master/src/SslCertBinding.Net.Sample.Tests/UnitTests.cs)