# Owin self host SSL connection reset

Tags: ssl, https, owin, self-hosting, netsh

I got an issue when setting up HTTPs for a self host Owin console application.  The browser always shows a connection reset error.

I've tried creating certificates manually according to this link http://chavli.com/how-to-configure-owin-self-hosted-website-with-ssl/ but I still get the connection reset issue on that port.
And I've checked the windows event log and there's no error messages.

The application will create X509 certificate by itself and run netsh command automatically.

Without Ssl, the application can display the web page correctly.

Can any one run my code below and see whether it can work on your computer?
Thanks in advance.

*Need to add COM reference CertEnroll 1.0 Type Library to compile the code below (vs2015 already contains this COM reference in Type Libraries)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using CERTENROLLLib;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using AppFunc = System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task>;

namespace Owin.Startup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int port = 8888;
            string url = $"https://localhost:{port}";
            var cert = GetCert("localhost", TimeSpan.FromDays(3650), "devpwd", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "cert.dat");
            ActivateCert(cert, port, GetAppId());
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Hosted: {url}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        static private string GetAppId()
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            //The following line (part of the original answer) is misleading.
            //**Do not** use it unless you want to return the System.Reflection.Assembly type's GUID.
            //Console.WriteLine(assembly.GetType().GUID.ToString());

            // The following is the correct code.
            var attribute = (GuidAttribute)assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(GuidAttribute), true)[0];
            var id = attribute.Value;
            return id;
        }
        static public X509Certificate2 GetCert(string cn, TimeSpan expirationLength, string pwd = "", string filename = null)
        {
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339706/how-to-create-self-signed-certificate-programmatically-for-wcf-service
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629395/http-listener-with-https-support-coded-in-c-sharp
            // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.storename(v=vs.110).aspx
            // create DN for subject and issuer
            var base64encoded = string.Empty;
            if (filename != null && File.Exists(filename))
            {
                base64encoded = File.ReadAllText(filename);
            }
            else
            {
                base64encoded = CreateCertContent(cn, expirationLength, pwd);
                if (filename != null)
                {
                    File.WriteAllText(filename, base64encoded);
                }
            }
            // instantiate the target class with the PKCS#12 data (and the empty password)
            var rlt = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2(
                System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64encoded), pwd,
                // mark the private key as exportable (this is usually what you want to do)
                // mark private key to go into the Machine store instead of the current users store
                X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet
                );
            return rlt;
        }

        private static string CreateCertContent(string cn, TimeSpan expirationLength, string pwd)
        {
            string base64encoded = string.Empty;
            var dn = new CX500DistinguishedName();
            dn.Encode("CN=" + cn, X500NameFlags.XCN_CERT_NAME_STR_NONE);

            CX509PrivateKey privateKey = new CX509PrivateKey();
            privateKey.ProviderName = "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider";
            privateKey.Length = 2048;
            privateKey.KeySpec = X509KeySpec.XCN_AT_KEYEXCHANGE;
            privateKey.KeyUsage = X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_DECRYPT_FLAG |
                                  X509PrivateKeyUsageFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_KEY_AGREEMENT_FLAG;
            privateKey.MachineContext = true;
            privateKey.ExportPolicy = X509PrivateKeyExportFlags.XCN_NCRYPT_ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_EXPORT_FLAG;
            privateKey.Create();

            // Use the stronger SHA512 hashing algorithm
            var hashobj = new CObjectId();
            hashobj.InitializeFromAlgorithmName(ObjectIdGroupId.XCN_CRYPT_HASH_ALG_OID_GROUP_ID,
                ObjectIdPublicKeyFlags.XCN_CRYPT_OID_INFO_PUBKEY_ANY,
                AlgorithmFlags.AlgorithmFlagsNone, "SHA512");

            // Create the self signing request
            var cert = new CX509CertificateRequestCertificate();
            cert.InitializeFromPrivateKey(X509CertificateEnrollmentContext.ContextMachine, privateKey, "");
            cert.Subject = dn;
            cert.Issuer = dn; // the issuer and the subject are the same
            cert.NotBefore = DateTime.Now.Date;
            // this cert expires immediately. Change to whatever makes sense for you
            cert.NotAfter = cert.NotBefore + expirationLength;
            cert.HashAlgorithm = hashobj; // Specify the hashing algorithm
            cert.Encode(); // encode the certificate

            // Do the final enrollment process
            var enroll = new CX509Enrollment();
            enroll.InitializeFromRequest(cert); // load the certificate
            enroll.CertificateFriendlyName = cn; // Optional: add a friendly name
            string csr = enroll.CreateRequest(); // Output the request in base64
            // and install it back as the response
            enroll.InstallResponse(InstallResponseRestrictionFlags.AllowUntrustedCertificate,
                csr, EncodingType.XCN_CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, pwd); // no password
            // output a base64 encoded PKCS#12 so we can import it back to the .Net security classes
            base64encoded = enroll.CreatePFX(pwd, // no password, this is for internal consumption
                PFXExportOptions.PFXExportChainWithRoot);
            return base64encoded;
        }

        private static void ActivateCert(X509Certificate2 rlt, int port, string appId)
        {
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            if (!store.Certificates.Contains(rlt))
            {
                store.Add(rlt);

                ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.FileName = "netsh";

                psi.Arguments = $"http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port}";
                Process procDel = Process.Start(psi);
                procDel.WaitForExit();

                psi.Arguments = $"http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{port} certhash={rlt.Thumbprint} appid={{{appId}}}";
                Process proc = Process.Start(psi);
                proc.WaitForExit();

                psi.Arguments = $"http delete sslcert ipport=[::]:{port}";
                Process procDelV6 = Process.Start(psi);
                procDelV6.WaitForExit();

                psi.Arguments = $"http add sslcert ipport=[::]:{port} certhash={rlt.Thumbprint} appid={{{appId}}}";
                Process procV6 = Process.Start(psi);
                procV6.WaitForExit();

                psi.Arguments = $"http add urlacl url=https://+:{port}/ user={Environment.UserDomainName}\\{Environment.UserName}";
                Process procAcl = Process.Start(psi);
                procAcl.WaitForExit();
            }
            store.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Startup
    {
        private IAppBuilder app;
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
#if DEBUG
            app.UseErrorPage();
#endif

            app.Use(new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(next => (async env =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Begin Request");
                foreach (var i in env.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t={(env[i] == null ? "null" : env[i].ToString())}\t#\t{(env[i] == null ? "null" : env[i].GetType().FullName)}");
                }
                if (next != null)
                {
                    await next.Invoke(env);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Process Complete");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("End Request");
            })));

            app.UseWelcomePage("/");

            this.app = app;
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with your hand-crafted cert so it fails after establishing the initial connection. There may be something in the event logs. Try using those cert generation tools and see if you can make it work.

Comment: I tried creating the certificate manually using IIS but still got the connection reset issue.  I tried on 2 different computers with the same steps mentioned above and both give me a ssl connection reset error on that port.  I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not create certificate with the base64 content which loaded from the cert.dat.  Try using cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, pwd) and load it with new X509Certificate2(filename, pwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);