# HTTPS with HTTPLISTENER NO ENCRYPTION

Tags: .net, https

I follow are these steps from the link.

[Httplistener with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support/24201221#24201221)

All is working well, but no encryption is on. (I looked with wireshark) Can anybody help?

Thanks.Cit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test a new certificate like the way is discribed by "http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=735306" and now is it working.

PS: You have to know, with wireshark you cann't look at localhostloopback! The best is, you Work with two device for test.

bye.cit