# Configuration of HttpListener with https

Tags: c#, netsh

I'm looking for a best pratice:

I'm having a webdav-implementation that is using the HttpListener. Since I require https I configure the connection using

```
netsh http add ...
```

(...taken from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/1623426 ) an it works fine.

What is best practice here?

Do I have to register and unregister the certificate at the start/exit of my application everytime?

Or do I have to set this up only one time at the installation of my application?