# ServiceStack communications with Windows Service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services, servicestack

I have an multi layered application that I have developed.  I communicate with the windows service using http with ServiceStack (AppHostHttpListenerBase).  While this works fine in clean environments, I often find that customers computers are not so clean and one of the first problem areas is the introduction of an unwanted Proxy with causes my application not to run.  I get alot of bad press that the application does not work well, when in reality it is a result of a hidden issue on the customer machine.
When I go to query my endpoints the proxy interferes and I lose all communications with the Service.

I am thinking of going back to WCF and using namedpipes but before I do so, wondered if there was a better way in the ServiceStack world (Which I absolutely love)
Ideas?  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If a local HTTP proxy is causing issues one thing you could try is to use SSL which will let you tunnel your traffic as an opaque binary through their proxy minimizing potential for interference.

Configuring SSL for HttpListener is configured the same way for all HttpListener's, i.e. it's not specific to ServiceStack - and it needs to be configured on the OS where it's run.

This answer shows how to configure SSL on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/85785

You'll be able to use https with ServiceStack HttpListener self-host by following the steps above, I used "https://*:8443/" for the url and "CN=localhost" to bypass the SSL browser warning dialog.

It's not specifically clear in the answer but you can get the Thumbprint from the details tab of the certificate where you then need to remove spaces. If it's easier, you can follow the walkthrough in the answer below to use MMC to import the certificate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905011/85785

Comment: But this would require a certificate to be installed on each computer.  This is an app sold to consumers...  not feasible.

Comment: @Jeff Was more thinking of a potential work around for the problematic clients.