# ServiceStack SelfHost SSL Support

Tags: ssl, servicestack, self-hosting

i am trying to find a way to enable SSL on SelfHost ServiceStack, 
as this requires administrative rights today for using "Net SH", as well as the fact this is "Not Clean" as i need to maintain the Port outside of my application configuration, manage removal if port Change, etc.

any help will be awesome.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring ServiceStack HttpListener with SSL is the same as [configuring any HttpListener with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11457719/85785).

My previous answer contains more details on [configuring ServiceStack HttpListener with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511914/85785).