# Send https request from JavaScript to c# on localhost

Tags: javascript, c#, https, httplistener

I want to make a request from a web site to a desktop application.
I use javascript to send a post http request to localhost
(http://localhost:8080/{my site}) and I listen with my c# desktop
application using httplistner to receive the request
and send back the response.
All that is working great.
The problem starts when my site is using https. Then to make this work I have to use https in my calls to the localhost
as well.
I have created a self-signed certificate to localhost and
I do not get an error from the browser by the httplistner
is not catching my requests.

There is another stack overflow question that was answered in:
[Httplistener with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support)
My problem is making the httpslistner work after i have installed
the certificate. until now the listner does not catch my requests in https.

Does anyone know how can I make this work or do you have
a better way of communicating between web-JS and desktop application
(has to work on all modern browsers).

Thanks,
tomer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Httplistener with https support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support)

Comment: I did something similar in the past using Firebase's REST API and the JavaScript library.  

https://firebase.google.com/docs/  

Worked for me

Comment: I do not want to install other 3rd party libraries if do not have to.

Comment: I have recently implement HTTPS using HTTPListener. There is no any input required, everything is handled by C# code. I have shared my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58149405/983548