# How to use SSL with Ggrapevine 3.1

Tags: c#, rest, grapevine

I want to add SSL support to my REST server. I use Grapvine 3.1.

I did some web research but I only find SSL releated information for Grapevine version 4.

Is SSL supported with version 3.1? If yes is there any documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSL with Grapevine 3.1 is just as easy, from the code side, as it is with 4.x.

**Grapevine 4.x:**

```cs
server.UseHttps = true;
```

**Grapevine 3.1**

Use the `protocol` constructor argument or change the property before starting the server.

```cs
var server = new RestServer(protocol: "https");
server.Protocol = "https";
```

**Both Versions**

In addition to that, you will need to create a certificate and configure the machine that the server is running on to use that certificate. If that's new to you, I'll refer you to [this post on setting up HTTPS support for HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support).