# Simple Client/Server Application using SSL in C#

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am trying to add SSL to a very basic client/server application : the client sends 2 numbers, the server computes the addition and return it to the client.

I am using a valid self signed certificates, already used in Java Application, though I did not install them in the system, I dont know if it is mandatory in C#.

Here is the server code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SimpleHttpServerSSL
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            string serverCertPath = "C:\\server\\server_key.p12";  
            string serverCertPassword = "myPassword"; 
            

            const string url = "https://localhost:8080/add"; 
            var server = new HttpListener();
            server.Prefixes.Add(url + "/");
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server is listening at " + url);

          

            while (true)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = await server.GetContextAsync();
                HandleClientRequest(context, serverCertPath, serverCertPassword);
            }
        }

        private static void Log(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Log: " + message);
        }

        private static void HandleClientRequest(HttpListenerContext context, string serverCertPath, string serverCertPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
                {
                    var data = new
                    {
                        A = 0,
                        B = 0
                    };

                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream))
                    {
                        string requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        data = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(requestBody, data);
                    }

                    var result = data.A + data.B;

                    var responseObj = new
                    {
                        R = result
                    };

                    string responseJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObj);
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseJson);
                    context.Response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    context.Response.OutputStream.Close();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Received request: A = {data.A}, B = {data.B}, Result = {result}");
                }
                else
                {
                    context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
                }

                context.Response.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception happend: " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
            
    }
}
```

And here is the client code:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SimpleHttpClient
{
    class Program
    {

        static void LogException(Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + error.GetBaseException().ToString());
        }
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter value for A:");
                int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("Enter value for B:");
                int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                var data = new
                {
                    A = a,
                    B = b
                };

                string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                string clientCertPath = "C:\\client\\client.pfx";  
                string clientCertPassword = "myPassword";  


                var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); 
                handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(clientCertPath, clientCertPassword));

                handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };


                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
                {
                    const string serverUrl = "https://localhost:8080/add"; 

                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(serverUrl, content);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var resultObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(responseBody, new { R = 0 });
                        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + resultObj.R);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + response.StatusCode);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a SocketException, connection closed by distant host:

```
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): Une connexion existante a dû être fermée par l'hôte distant.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveAsync(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(Memory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, Boolean fromNetworkStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.FillHandshakeBufferAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Int32 minSize)
```

How can I fix the code / debug if anything is wrong during handshake without using Wireshark (too many restictions by our IT, it may not work properly) ?

Comment: Please post error message in English.

Comment: Sorry, but could not change the locale to us-en, it did not work, I translated it just above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `HttpListener` is not using your self signed certificate.
You need to associate the certificate to the port 8080 using netsh command with these arguments

```
netsh.exe http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:{0} certhash={1} appid={{2}}
```

Where {0} is your port.

Where {1} is your certificate thumbprint installed in your certificate store.

Where {2} is a GUID that represents your application.

A complete description for [netsh command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh-http). Or you could use kestrel that does not need any system command to use a certificate

Another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403333/httplistener-with-https-support) dealing with HTTPS and `HttpListener`

Comment: This means that I have to install the certifiates in the system. I dont want to install test certificates. I think that it must work without that

Comment: HttpListener uses HTTP.sys and you won't be able to use it without that, if I'm not mistaken. You can switch to kestrel though ;)

Comment: You are right, it worked, but I had to import the Root.p12 and Server.p12 to local machine (import to current user did not work (netsh returned error 1312) ).